# wp_list_comments reply-link throws Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm experiencing some unexpected behaviors when using `wp_list_comments`.

Generated link:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="http://localhost/mypost/?replytocom=2#respond" onclick="return addComment.moveForm( &quot;div-comment-2&quot;, &quot;2&quot;, &quot;respond&quot;, &quot;9&quot; )" aria-label="reply to NAME">Reply</a>
```

When I click the **reply** link the JavaScript console throws an error:

I was *expecting* that the textarea will show up under the current comment upon clicking the reply button.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
    at Object.moveForm (comment-reply.min.js?ver=4.9.4:1)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM18269:489)
```

Now to the unexpected behaviours. Im using the Plugin AdvancedCustomFields. When I disable the plugin the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addComment is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM18404:489)
```

To solve this particular problem i've tried to manually add the `comment-reply.js`

### functions.php

```
// enable reply to comments 
function theme_queue_js(){
if ( (!is_admin()) && is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments') )
  wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_queue_js');
```

This however is not enqueing the script as expected. Still throwing `Uncaught ReferenceError` (note the ACF Plugin is still disabled).

### comments.php

```
    <ul id="comments">
    <?php wp_list_comments(array(
        'walker'            => null,
        'max_depth'         => '',
        'style'             => 'ul',
        'callback'          => null,
        'end-callback'      => null,
        'type'              => 'comment',
        'reply_text'        => 'Reply',
        'page'              => '',
        'per_page'          => '',
        'avatar_size'       => 32,
        'reverse_top_level' => null,
        'reverse_children'  => '',
        'format'            => 'html5', // or 'xhtml' if no 'HTML5' theme support
        'short_ping'        => false,   // @since 3.6
        'echo'              => true     // boolean, default is true
    )); ?>
    </ul>
```

### Some more-or-less useful informations:

- I am using the `comment-list` theme support
- I've cleared the cache
- I've used multiple other browsers (logged in & logged out)
- There are **no** other javascript errors thrown

I did a fair amount of research already. I've also stumbled upon an situation where the LastPass Extension caused the errors above. But the given solutions (disabling and/or logout from the extension) for that, didn't work out me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (at least for me) was to add `comment_form()`.

I managed to oversee this simple function for hours.

```
<div id="comments">
<ul>
    <?php wp_list_comments(array(
        'walker'            => null,
        'max_depth'         => '',
        'style'             => 'ul',
        'callback'          => null,
        'end-callback'      => null,
        'type'              => 'comment',
        'reply_text'        => 'Reply',
        'page'              => '',
        'per_page'          => '',
        'avatar_size'       => 32,
        'reverse_top_level' => null,
        'reverse_children'  => '',
        'format'            => 'html5', // or 'xhtml' if no 'HTML5' theme support
        'short_ping'        => false,   // @since 3.6
        'echo'              => true     // boolean, default is true
    )); ?>
</ul>

<?php comment_form(); ?>
```